# Check Box with Lazy Adapter in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a strange issue which is totally weird. I have implemented Lazy Adapter to my project using the help of [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

I have added checked box to the custom ListView. The data is showing fine, but the strange issue is that when I check the first row in my list and scroll down I can see another item checked. This is happening everything 7th item on my list. The item is checked automatically. I am not why is this happening?

can somebody help me fix this?

This is my:

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pic" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/NameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".70"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friendsName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Results will show up here"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutforCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" />
 </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**listItem.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgrnd"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".88"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        style="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:scrollX="0px"
        android:scrollY="0px"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="20dip"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your views are being recycled.

If the checkbox of the first row is ticked and you scroll up. When the first view disappears from the screen, the same row is going to be used for the bottom row which is appearing from the bottom of the screen.

The best way to avoid this is to have persistent flag in your data model. If the flag is set to true for a position then set the checkbox to be checked and uncheck when it is false (uncheck is very important)

I hope that it helps

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/hoomi/HuffleChallenge/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/hooman/ostovari/huddle/ui/FriendsArrayAdapter.java